# Titanium Android webView evalJS does not deal well with typeof

Tags: android, webview, eval, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I've got a webview in my Titanium app that returns an empty string when I ask it to check for the typeof a variable. The point of this exercise is figuring out if a function exists on a page that reloads itself in different forms.

```
var hasAuth = self.registerView.evalJS("typeof authenticate;")
```

This works fine in iOS, and in fact in Android it works on many occasions as well. Yet on Android, it will sometimes return nothingness, represented as 'undefined.'

PS: No, the problem is not about including 'return' in the javascript string. Titanium does that for you and it will causes errors if you do it too.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in this case turns out to be:

```
var hasAuth = self.registerView.evalJS("'' + typeof authenticate;")
```

Somehow evalJS can get the typeof to work, but not if the line starts with typeof.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Titanium's webView load event is that it often fires too early. At least on Android. When it fires too early, there is not yet a 'authenticate' function whose type can be returned.

So the problem is not with evalJS, it's with the timing of the load event.